# Calling one function inside of another error: "no matching function for call to `merge(int*&, int&, int&, int&)"

Tags: c++

2 functions have been used merge() and mergesort(). mergesort() is trying to call merge but "no matching function" error is displayed.

the same error is not encountered when I use a class to write this code

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;


    //MERGE SORT
    void mergesort(int arr[],int l,int h)
    {
         int m=(l+h)/2;
         if(l<h)
         {
                mergesort(arr,l,m-1);
                mergesort(arr,m,h);
                merge(arr,l,h,m);
         }
    }

    //CALLING THIS FUNCTION IN mergesort() IS GIVING AN ERROR
    void merge(int arr[],int l,int h,int m)
    {
         int a1[m-l];
         int a2[h-m+1];

         int i=l,j=m,ptr=0;

         while(i<m&&j<h+1)
         {
                         if(a1[i]<a2[j])
                         {
                                        arr[ptr++]=a1[i++];
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             arr[ptr++]=a2[j++];
                         }
         }

         if(i<m)
         {
                for(int k=i;k<m;k++)
                {
                        arr[ptr++]=a1[k];
                }
         }
         else
         {
             for(int k=j;k<h+1;k++)
                {
                        arr[ptr++]=a2[k];
                }
         }
    }
    void printarray(int arr[], int n)
    {
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         cout<<arr[i];
    }

    int main()
    {
        int arr[]={12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};
        mergesort(arr,0,5);
        printarray(arr,6);

        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: In C++ you need to declare everything *before* you use it. For example, if you have a function and want to call it, you need to *declare* the function before the call.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the merge function first because the compiler doesnt know 
   how many parameters should take and what type of each of those parameters

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge (int [], int, int, int);
//MERGE SORT
void mergesort(int arr[],int l,int h)
{
     int m=(l+h)/2;
     if(l<h)
     {
            mergesort(arr,l,m-1);
            mergesort(arr,m,h);
            merge(arr,l,h,m);
     }
}

//CALLING THIS FUNCTION IN mergesort() IS GIVING AN ERROR
void merge(int arr[],int l,int h,int m)
{
     int a1[m-l];
     int a2[h-m+1];

     int i=l,j=m,ptr=0;

     while(i<m&&j<h+1)
     {
                     if(a1[i]<a2[j])
                     {
                                    arr[ptr++]=a1[i++];
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         arr[ptr++]=a2[j++];
                     }
     }

     if(i<m)
     {
            for(int k=i;k<m;k++)
            {
                    arr[ptr++]=a1[k];
            }
     }
     else
     {
         for(int k=j;k<h+1;k++)
            {
                    arr[ptr++]=a2[k];
            }
     }
}
void printarray(int arr[], int n)
{
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     cout<<arr[i];
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};
    mergesort(arr,0,5);
    printarray(arr,6);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this line before the declaration of the `mergesort` function:

```
void merge(int arr[],int l,int h,int m);
```

Alternatively, you can swap the functions `merge` and `mergesort`, so that the latter is declared before the former.

In general, you cannot refer a function that has not declare anywhere.
The line above introduce the `merge` function, even if the definition is held up after the `mergesort` on.
This way, the prototype of that function is known and it can be used from within the other one.